# problems while creating MVC 5 application users programmatically from winforms application

Tags: winforms, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I am new to mvc and asp.net and trying to understand basics. 
I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 application using default authentication. It created default AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles`enter code here` tables.

I also have a winforms application in VS 2015 that have to create the mvc application users programmatically. Both applications use same database.

```
private static async Task<bool> CreateNewWebUser(string email, string mobile, string roleId)
{
    try
    {
        string result = String.Empty;
        var user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = email,
            Email = email,
        };
        var db = new ComplianceEntities();
        var dbrole = db.AspNetRoles.Find(roleId);
        var usermanager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new IdentityDbContext()));
        if (usermanager.FindByName(email) == null)
        {
            var res = await  usermanager.CreateAsync(user, "round(lue29");
            if (res.Succeeded)
            {
                var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ComplianceEntities()));
                if (!roleManager.RoleExists("ROLE NAME"))
                {
                    var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
                    role.Name = dbrole.Name;
                    roleManager.Create(role);
                }
                usermanager.AddToRole(user.Id, dbrole.Name);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In app.config I added

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" >
<parameters>
  <parameter value="Data Source=myDatabase; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
</parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>

<system.web>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<roleManager enabled="true" />
</system.web>
```

Before I added rolemanager piece of code, i got an error saying Role "user" was not found. 
after I added the code, the code now fails at 
`if (usermanager.FindByName(email) == null)`
as the usermanager has the email and user that I was trying to create but the user is not found AspNetUsers table. I am not sure where it created. When i inspected the users in usermanager they dont have roles associated with them.

Note: `IdentityDbContext()` is refering to the class in `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`.
`ComplianceEntities()` is refering to the entity class that was created by EF in framework library

```
public partial class ComplianceEntities : DbContext
{
    public ComplianceEntities()
    : base("name=ComplianceEntities")
    {
    }
}
```

I have been on it from past six hours and Please shed some light on my problem.

Thank you